# How to view Dask dashboard when running on a virtual machine?

Tags: linux, python-3.x, centos, virtual-machine, dask

Here is what I'm doing now:

- From my Windows laptop, I SSH into Linux server via Putty: IP address is `11.11.11.111`
- Start up Jupyter notebook: `nohup jupyter notebook --ip=0.0.0.0 --no-browser &`

  - Terminal output shows Jupyter notebook is running at:
  - `http://(11.11.11.111 or 127.0.0.1):8889/?token=blahblahblah`
- Start single machine client in a new notebook:

  ```
  from dask.distributed import Client
  client = Client()
  ```

Printing `client` shows that the dashboard is located at `http://127.0.0.1:8787/status`, however, I cannot find the dashboard at that URL. I've also tried `http://11.11.11.111:8787/status` but that didn't work either.

I'm still able to run everything in my notebook with Dask Dataframes just fine, but I just can't figure out how to view the dashboard. `Bokeh` is installed on server and I'm running Jupyter Notebook through Anaconda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally figured it out with some SSH Tunneling.

More background on problem:

- Local machine is a Windows laptop
- Remote server is a CentOS box

The goal is actually two-fold:

1. Run Jupyter Notebook on remote server that contains Dask code
2. View Dask Dashboard from code running in Notebook

Here are the steps I took:

1. For this example, IP Address of remote server is `11.11.11.111`
2. Following some instructions for [Port Tunneling](https://blog.devolutions.net/2017/4/how-to-configure-an-ssh-tunnel-on-putty), I use `8001` as the Source Port and Destination is `localhost:8889`
3. After connecting to the remote server (which has **16** cores and 44.7GB of RAM), I ran this in Putty terminal: `dask-worker tcp://11.11.11.111:8786 --memory-limit=auto --nthreads=1 --nprocs=16 &`
4. Start Jupyter Notebook on server: `jupyter notebook --ip=0.0.0.0 --port=8889 --no-browser &`

   a. After running above command, output shows that Jupyter notebook is running at `http://(hostname or 127.0.0.1):8889/?token=blahblahblah`

   b. Opening a browser and going to the URL above (`http://hostname:8889/?token=blahblahblah`) brings to Jupyter Notebook home page
5. Create new Notebook and run following code:

   ```
   import dask.dataframe as dd
   from dask.distributed import Client
   client = Client('11.11.11.111:8786')
   print(client)
   ```

The output shows dashboard

```
    Client
    Scheduler: tcp://11.11.11.111:8786
    Dashboard: http://11.11.11.111:36124/status
    client = Client('11.11.11.111:8786')

    Cluster
    Workers: 16
    Cores: 16
    Memory: 44.70 GB
```

Now typing `http://11.11.11.111:36124/status` into a browser window takes me to the Dask Dashboard.